What is $A\otimes_k (A/k)$?
Let $A$ is an associative algebra over a field $k$, I want to understand $A\otimes_k (A/k)$. Parenthesis matter (as this is often written in terms of $\bar A=A/k$). I'm happy if I know this for $k=\mathbb C$.
As far as I know, the tensor product construction for algebras is that of the underlying vector spaces. So, for scalars
$x\in k^\times$, one has $(ax \otimes b) = (a\otimes x b)$ for $a,b \in A$. But in
$A\otimes_k (A/k)$, one has
$$
(ax\otimes \bar b) = a \otimes x \bar b = a \otimes \bar b
$$
where $\bar b$ is the equivalence class in $A/k$; consequently, there, the scalar's action disappears in the second factor.  This seems erroneous since, the same way, another
constant $y\in k^\times, y\neq x$ could pop up on the rhs and we could reverse the argument to deduce
$ax \otimes \bar b= a y\otimes \bar b$.
If I didn't make a mistake, it seems  $A\otimes_k (A/k)$ is  $(A\otimes_k A)/k$.

What is $A/k$? Surely it's not a quotient algebra, since $k$ is not an ideal?

Sure, that observation solves it, thanks. ($A$ was unital, overseen.)
